# Contact form PHP / HTML / JS - Phone not printing

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to figure out why my phone string is the only one not being printed in the received email from the contact form.

I have the following:

HTML:

```html
<input 
id="phone"                    
type="text"
name="phone"
placeholder="Telefone"
/>
```

PHP:

```php
include_once (dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/config.php');

$response = null;

if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch ($action) {
        case "SendMessage": {
                if (isset($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["email"])) {
                    $message = $_POST["message"];
                    $message .= "<br/><br/>";  
                    $message .= "phone:".$_POST["phone"];                                

                    $response = (SendEmail($message, $_POST["subject"], $_POST["name"], $_POST["email"], $email)) ? 'Mensagem Enviada!!' : "Sending Message Failed";
                } else {
                    $response = "Sending Message Failed";
                }
            }
            break;
        default: {
                $response = "Invalid action is set! Action is: " . $action;
            }
    }
}
```

JS:

```js
function SendMail() {
        $('.contact-form [type="submit"]').on('click', function () {
            var emailVal = $('#contact-email').val();
            if (isValidEmailAddress(emailVal)) {
                var params = {
                    'action': 'SendMessage',
                    'name': $('#name').val(),
                    'email': $('#contact-email').val(),
                    'phone': $('#phone').val(),
                    'subject': $('#subject').val(),
                    'message': $('#message').val()
                };
```

As i said, everything else is being received on our email, but the phone string.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: did you get any clue in the debugger? starting putting a breakpoint in the php code dealing with the form data coming from the request. How does it look? does it contain the phone data? And if not, can you traverse the "call stack" doing one step behind and checking if the $('#subject').val() has the right value when you craft the http request before sending it?

Comment: what `var_dump($_POST)` says right after `isset($_POST["action"])`?

Comment: 1. Ensure it's received in php: dump `$_POST` content to file. 2. Open dev tools in your email page and inspect place where it should be phone number, maybe email client removes it as possible security issue. (e.g. `phone:1235` converts to `<a href="phone:1235"></a>`